# How to you run Backup-​Azure​Key​Vault​Secret - says doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault

I am wanting to do a back up of one key vault and restore it to another.  But, as far as I can tell, this API that is well documented, doesn't really exist.  There is the Backup-​Azure​Key​Vault​Secret as well as Backup of other KeyVault items, and they simply don't seem to exist anywhere.  I like the idea - it can only be restored to that subscription - and I need to duplicate a key vault.  (There should be a Backup-​Azure​Key​Vault​ but I can't find any docs on that)

I've tried running it powershell - where I can run commands to get or set keys, certs etc and all the other commands work.

I tried running it from the portal's command window and it doesn't run there either.

I tried upgrading the Module: AzureRM.KeyVault - but it says it wasn't installed using the same tool that I was trying to upgrade it with, so it failed.

I just installed the tools, including powershell within the last month, so unless this came out in the last month I'd think that it would just work.

Thanks.

Update:   I typed the command by hand to avoid any 'special chars' in the command, then I retyped it to make sure the case was exactly the same?
[image]

What am I missing?

Update 2:
   I listed all the commands using 'get-command' stored it in a file, and 'grep'ed it for AzureRM.KeyVault  and this is the output  (I can backup/restore Keys but not Certs or Secrets??):

```
Cmdlet          Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                       2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificateContact                2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Add-AzureKeyVaultKey                               2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Backup-AzureKeyVaultKey                            2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                       2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateContact                2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateIssuer                 2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation              2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy                 2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultKey                               2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret                            2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmKeyVault                                2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                    2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          New-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAdministratorDetails   2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          New-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOrganizationDetails    2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy                 2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmKeyVault                                2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                    2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificateContact             2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificateIssuer              2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation           2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey                            2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureKeyVaultSecret                         2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmKeyVault                             2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy                 2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Restore-AzureKeyVaultKey                           2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAttribute              2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateIssuer                 2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy                 2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttribute                      2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret                            2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureKeyVaultSecretAttribute                   2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy                    2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Cmdlet          Stop-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation             2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault
```

Comment: That error is usually pretty accurate in that PS can't find the cmdlets... it could be a bad install or incorrect path, etc...  If you run `Get-Module AzureRM.KeyVault -ListAvailable` what does it return?  And is Backup-* one of the exported cmds?

Comment: ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands     
Manifest   2.1.0      AzureRM.KeyVault                    {Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate, Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAttribute, Stop-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation, Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation...}

Comment: It cuts it off, so there is no way to know :-(   It says it is 2.1.0 though, is that the issue?

Comment: I just tried just 'Get-module -all' and it showed 'Backup-AzureKeyVaultKey...' which, I verified I was able to run that command (to backup a key), but the Secret one doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I think I figured it out.   I ran:  Install-Module -Name AzureRM -allowclobber  (AllowClobber required, it is also untrusted from PowerShell Gallery), and then when I ran the command it asked me if I wanted to run it, I said A, and then it gave me an error saying the command didn't exist.  I did the same thing as Admin and it ran.  It now shows up in the list, and can be run (as admin only)  I had tried running as admin before and it failed.  Apparently, recently installing Power Shell, it installed version 2.1, and the current is 4.1   - Sounds like updates were needed to the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you provide has some special characters, it is the reason that you could use the command.

[image]

Please use command [`Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/backup-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-4.1.0). You could look carefully they are different. `-​` is wrong.

Update:

If it does not work for you, I suggest you could install Azure PowerShell with .msi installer, you could download it from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: so? that doesnt prove anything, he used another symbol on the forum, doesnt mean that the same was used on the console, he provided no logs

Comment: To be fair, one of the commands I tried did have funky chars in it, so on that attempt, it did have the chars in it.  However, I've updated the question to include a screen shot that I typed by hand, without doing a cut and paste.   Also, I copied and pasted your text above and tried it and got the same result.  I also retried this with the arguments, tried it with exact case.

Comment: @TraderhutGames It seems that you Azure Power Shell is not installed correctly, I suggest you could install the latest version from .msi installer, you could check my answer.

Comment: Reinstalled from the link, seems happy now.